# Smarty output to PHP Constant is it possible?

Tags: php, constants, smarty

I got constant in PHP

This constant is written in Mysql

With Smarty i am doing output to HTML

Is it possible to output Smarty results to php not to HTML

```
<? {$CONSTANTS_RESULT[LOOP]} ?>
```

?

Comment: Answer is simple (I think), but first go back and accept some answers to your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access PHP constants in Smarty, you can use `{$smarty.const.MY_CONSTANT}` which is [documented here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.const).

Comment: You dont uderstand. I want results from mysql to be threat as constants. In simple word. I want smarty to throw results not to HTML but to PHP, so PHP could use results as Constants.

Comment: You would send a query to mysql to retrieve the information, then use define() to make it a constant. Smarty is really only for output to html, not for communicating with the database. Define documentation:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: So I can not send Smarty output to PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
$smarty->registerFilter('pre',array($this,'preFilterConstants'));

// '#' Const in Smarty...
public function preFilterConstants($strInput, $objSmarty) {
  return preg_replace('|(<!--\{[^\}]+)#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(.+?\}-->)|si','$1\$smarty.const.$2$3',$strInput);
}
```

and do:

```
<? <!--{#MY_CONSTANT}--> ?>
```

if you want to use other delimiter just edit pattern...